# Model View Presenter with an EventBus, how to get Events back to Presenter?

Tags: android, mvp, event-bus, otto

I am using the Model-View-Presenter design pattern coupled with an EventBus (Otto). The entire reason I implemented this pattern is to decouple events to the presenter only, and have the presenter update the views.

This is an example of some of the code I have, I'll use getting `Events` as an example. (Please note that `Events` is different from the `EventBus` `Event`, meaning an `Event` in `Events` is an event like "Dad's Birthday", but an `Event` in the `EventBus` is a Bus-event).

**Fragment**

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment {

    private EventPresenter mEventPresenter;

    // Initialize boilerplate code...

    private void init() {
        mEventPresenter = new EventPresenter();
        mEventPresenter.loadEvents();
    }

    // I WANT TO MOVE THESE SUBSCRIPTION METHODS TO
    // MY PRESENTER OR SUBSCRIBER, BUT THEY ARE 
    // COUPLED TO THE ADAPTER OR A VIEW

    @Subscribe
    public void onEventsLoaded(EventsLoaded eventsLoaded) {
        List<Event> events = eventsLoaded.getEvents();
        mAdapter.setEvents(events);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEventJoined(EventJoined eventJoined) {
        mItemView.doAnimation();
        mTextView.setText("Leave");
        mAdapter.joinEvent(eventJoined.getEvent());
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onLeaveEvent(LeftEvent leftEvent) {
        mItemView.doAnimation();
        mTextView.setText("Join");
        mAdapter.leftEvent(leftEvent.getEvent());
    }

}
```

**Presenter**

```
public class EventPresenter {

    // This is the only method I have right now kind of defeats the purpose of 
    // having a presenter
    public void loadEvents() {
        EventBus.getInstance().post(new LoadEvents());
    }

}
```

**Subscriber**

```
public class EventSubscriber extends Subscriber {

    // This class is registered on the event bus

    @Subscribe
    public void onLoadEvents(LoadEvents loadEvents) {
        sClient.getEvents(new Callback<List<Event>>() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess(List<Event> events, Response response) {
                   EventBus.post(new EventsLoaded(events));
              }

              @Override
              public void onFailure(.....) {
                    // Handle failure
              }
          };
    }
}
```

How can I get the Presenters and the Subscribers to handle all the business logic, and have the Fragment only handle views?

Comment: may be subscribing events in presenter , with an instance of view inside it can help. Like presenter gets events from eventbus and call appropriate view method to update the UI.

Comment: Can you post an example answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not the best possibility but May Be help you out.

subscribing events in presenter , with an instance of view inside it can help. Like presenter gets events from eventbus and call appropriate view method to update the UI.

Mind that I have not changed method names of your fragment that updates UI and have passed event object directly from presenter which is indeed now a subscriber of events of eventbus. You can change it accordingly.

Fragment---

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment {

    private EventPresenter mEventPresenter;

    // Initialize boilerplate code...

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
         mEventPresenter.onResume();
    } 

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
         mEventPresenter.onPause();
    }  

    private void init() {
        mEventPresenter = new EventPresenter(this);
        mEventPresenter.loadEvents();
    }

    // I WANT TO MOVE THESE SUBSCRIPTION METHODS TO
    // MY PRESENTER OR SUBSCRIBER, BUT THEY ARE 
    // COUPLED TO THE ADAPTER OR A VIEW

    public void onEventsLoaded(EventsLoaded eventsLoaded) {
        List<Event> events = eventsLoaded.getEvents();
        mAdapter.setEvents(events);
    }

    public void onEventJoined(EventJoined eventJoined) {
        mItemView.doAnimation();
        mTextView.setText("Leave");
        mAdapter.joinEvent(eventJoined.getEvent());
    }

    public void onLeaveEvent(LeftEvent leftEvent) {
        mItemView.doAnimation();
        mTextView.setText("Join");
        mAdapter.leftEvent(leftEvent.getEvent());
    }

}
```

Presenter----

```
    public class EventPresenter {
        private EventFragment targetView; 
        public EventPresenter(EventFragment myView)
        {
             targetView = myView;

        }
        // This is the only method I have right now kind of defeats the purpose of 
        // having a presenter
        public void loadEvents() {
            EventBus.getInstance().post(new LoadEvents());
        }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEventsLoaded(EventsLoaded eventsLoaded) {
        targetView.onEventsLoaded(eventsLoaded);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEventJoined(EventJoined eventJoined) {
        targetView.onEventJoined(eventJoined);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onLeaveEvent(LeftEvent leftEvent) {
        targetView.onLeaveEvent(leftEvent);
    }


    public void onResume()
    {
         //subscride event bus
    } 


    public void onPause()
    {
         //unsubscride event bus
    }  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer, how would you handle something like fragment lifecycle methods? Or prevent an Activity from leaking when passed into the Presenter?

Comment: Also how would you unsubscribe the eventbus in the presenter?

Comment: My guess is that in the lifecycle method where the fragment or activity hits onPause or onDestroy, call a similar method in the presenter and unregister the bus, or set the target to null! Update your answer to include that and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is responsability to presenters to send or  receive events and after to notify fragment or activities

Comment: you save my time, Thanks